# Preserve IP address on Amazon Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have EC2 instance, that I wish to upgrade. Most likely will raise it to medium size. I am aware that if I upgrade the instance, I will loose the IP, it will be renewed. I have heard about Elastic IP, which preserves the IP address on all instance actions (restart, upgrade).

This is production server that I need to upgrade, but before doing so... can someone in short provide me the steps, to minimize the risk of doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With elastic IP, you get a static address associated with your account not with your EC2 instance.

On your EC2 Dashboard, you can allocate elastic IP address.

#### To associate an Elastic IP address with an instance

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console.
2. Click Elastic IPs in the navigation pane.
3. Select an EIP and click Associate Address.
4. In the Associate Address dialog box, select the instance from the
   Instance list box and click Associate.

Note: You will incur charges if it is **not** associated with any ec2 instance. So make sure you release the ips when not in use. AWS does this to get back unused addresses.

Comment: Answer accepted. I just did the same thing on Console. I am glad it was correct. Thank you for confirmation :)

Comment: When I do the steps you listed above, then my instance will be globally accessible using the IP that was assigned to by EIP? Yesterday I did basically the same steps, however my instance was not available using that IP. I had to remove the EIP. I will give it try later on.